Which approach should one follow if a pseudopotential underestimate/overestimate some electronic properties from experimental value?
I have seen during DFT calculation some authors comment that LDA/GGA functional overestimates/underestimates the band gap/lattice constant of some materials. Before going to the main calculation, it is recommended that we can plot phonon dispersion plot (say) to verify results with literature data so that future calculations goes well.
For example: my intention is to calculate optical properties (say dielectric function) of a material (say GaAs). And I am using a GGA functional which underestimate the band gap from experimental value. At that position, what should I do? Should I use that pseudopotential to run the necessary executables (scf, nscf, epsilon etc)? Or I have to improve the band gap first and make it close to experimental value and after that I should run the executables (scf, nscf, epsilon etc) to find out optical properties?

My recommendation will be to use better functionals. But if the optical properties you need depend only on the band gap, you can use the scissor operator that "fix" the over/under estimations by subtracting/adding the needed amount to the calculated gap to reproduce the experimental value.

Just a side note: changing pseudopotentials will not fix the band gap as long as the XC functionals used are LDA/GGA. So, instead of looking for better (and that comes with higher computational costs such as mBJ, hybrid, SCAN, etc) choice, maybe you can try some corrective approach such as DFT+U or DFT-1/2.

Just to add since you mentioned phonon dispersions: DFT is designed to predict accurate ground-state total-energy (and density), not excitation gap, band structure, etc. That is why phonons, geometry etc. are accurate, since they only depend on the total energy (or it's derivatives) and not on the band structure. The fact that DFT electronic structure is usually accurate is great, but sometimes it is very wrong. There is a lot of info in the literature about how to handle these cases (e,g. DFT+U, see @AbdulMuhaymin-FreePalestine comment!). Cheers!

@AbdulMuhaymin-FreePalestine, which program has DFT+1/2 implemented? I knew about a SIESTA modified version, but I couldn't configure to work.

@Camps one of the person from Lara Teles's research group replied to my similar question here. I didn't follow up and discarded the idea of using this since that time I only knew QE and QE support was not available. They have vasp support though. The python CLI can be found here - minushalf.

Thank you so much to all! Lots of good answers

The discussion in the comments section seems to have addressed the OPs question. If one wants to write a full answer, this community wiki can be deleted. From comments:

Camps: My recommendation will be to use better functionals. But if the optical properties you need depend only on the band gap, you can use the scissor operator that "fix" the over/under estimations by subtracting/adding the needed amount to the calculated gap to reproduce the experimental value.


Abdul Muhaymin -Free Palestine: Just a side note: changing pseudopotentials will not fix the band gap as long as the XC functionals used are LDA/GGA. So, instead of looking for better (and that comes with higher computational costs such as mBJ, hybrid, SCAN, etc) choice, maybe you can try some corrective approach such as DFT+U or DFT-1/2.


Tyler Sterling: Just to add since you mentioned phonon dispersions: DFT is designed to predict accurate ground-state total-energy (and density), not excitation gap, band structure, etc. That is why phonons, geometry etc. are accurate, since they only depend on the total energy (or it's derivatives) and not on the band structure. The fact that DFT electronic structure is usually accurate is great, but sometimes it is very wrong. There is a lot of info in the literature about how to handle these cases (e,g. DFT+U, see @AbdulMuhaymin-FreePalestine comment!). Cheers!

